# AggregationResults Type Cast MongoDB + Spring data + Aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm asking mongodb from my Spring data application using aggregation and when I get the result I need to cast it (or transform it) to my own object or type and I don't know how.

This is my code

```
AggregationResults aggregationResults = DBManager.getInstance().getMongoOperation().aggregate(aggregation, LevelEntity.class,Object.class);
```

I would like to have something like

```
AggregationResults<LevelList> aggregationResults = DBManager.getInstance().getMongoOperation().aggregate(aggregation, LevelEntity.class,LevelList.class);
```

and it gives me back this information

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "date" : "24/03/2015"
        },
        "levels" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54f8627071fdac0ec132b4e5"),
                        "_class" : "org.xxxxxxxxxxx.persistence.model.impl.LevelEntity",
                        "user" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("54da19ce71fd56a173a3451a"),
                                ...
                                ...
                                ...
                        },
                        "level" : 4,
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-24T14:04:32.830Z"),
                        "dateFormatted" : "24/03/2015"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54f8627071fdac0ec132b4f4"),
                        "_class" : "org.xxxxxxxxxxx.persistence.model.impl.LevelEntity",
                        "user" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("54e34bd671fde9071569650c"),
                                ...
                                ...
                                ...
                        },
                        "level" : 3,
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-03-24T14:04:32.866Z"),
                        "dateFormatted" : "24/03/2015"
                }
        ]
}
```

Can you please help me!!???

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use as follow

```
TypedAggregation<LevelList> aggregation=Aggregation.newAggregation(LevelList.class,
                match, sortOp, skipOp, limitOp);
AggregationResults<LevelList> data = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,
                COLLECTION_NAME, LevelList.class);
```

Comment: Cataclysm probably you don't know it but "I love you" ;)

Answer (score 1):

well Cataclysm your response is not totally correct but gave me the key to solve my problem, this is what I had to do

```
TypedAggregation<LevelEntity> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(LevelEntity.class,
                userMatchOperation, dateMatchOperation, group(LevelEntity.DATE_FORMATTED_FIELD).push(ROOT).as(LevelByDate.ENTITY_NAME));
        AggregationResults<LevelByDate> data = DBManager.getInstance().getMongoOperation().aggregate(aggregation, HappinessByDate.class);
```

And this is the LevelByDate object

```
@Document
public class LevelByDate {

    public static final String ENTITY_NAME = "levelEntity";

    @Id
    private String id;
    List<LevelEntity> levelEntity;

    public LevelByDate() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<LevelEntity> getLevelEntity() {
        return levelEntity;
    }

    public void setLevelEntity(List<LevelEntity> levelEntity) {
        this.levelEntity = levelEntity;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Kike.